# Truncate from alphanumeric string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find first alpha numeric substring and truncate the string starting from matched alpha numeric string

`test=k8s-configuration-int-mbus_config-int-mbus-deployment-db9c64cd-n4tww_central_6d499584`

Here first alpha numeric string is `-db9c64cd-` (it can be `-9dbc64cd-` too)

Now i want substring as `k8s-configuration-int-mbus_config-int-mbus-deployment`

Tried couple of regex like `re.sub(r'-[a-z0-9]*-.*', r'', test)` but did not work. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: string will have `-` at both ends where as k8s doesnt has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `re.sub` approach:

```sh
>>> import re
>>> test='k8s-configuration-int-mbus_config-int-mbus-deployment-db9c64cd-n4tww_central_6d499584'
>>> print (re.sub(r'(?i)-(?:[a-z]+\d[a-z\d]*|\d+[a-z][a-z\d]*)-.*', '', test))
k8s-configuration-int-mbus_config-int-mbus-deployment
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VoPYI4/2)

**RegEx Explained:**

- `(?i)`: Enable ignore case mode
- `-`: Match a hyphen
- `(?:[a-z]+\d[a-z\d]*|\d+[a-z][a-z\d]*)`: Match an alphanumeric string
- `-`: Match a hyphen
- `.*`: Match rest of the string

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
rx = r'^.*?(?=-(?:[A-Za-z]+[0-9]|[0-9]+[a-zA-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]*-)'
text = r'k8s-configuration-int-mbus_config-int-mbus-deployment-db9c64cd-n4tww_central_6d499584'
match = re.search(rx, text)
if match:
    print(match.group())
# => k8s-configuration-int-mbus_config-int-mbus-deployment
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a4GbCB/2) and [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/ErXQht).

Or, a splitting approach:

```py
import re
rx = r'-(?:[A-Za-z]+[0-9]|[0-9]+[a-zA-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]*-'
text = r'k8s-configuration-int-mbus_config-int-mbus-deployment-db9c64cd-n4tww_central_6d499584'
result = re.split(rx, text, 2)
print(result[0])
# => k8s-configuration-int-mbus_config-int-mbus-deployment
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/vyEkGE) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a4GbCB/1/).

**Regex details**

- `^` -  start of string
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=` - start of a positive lookahead:

  - `-` - a `-` char
  - `(?:[A-Za-z]+[0-9]|[0-9]+[a-zA-Z])` - one or more ASCII letters and a digit, or one or more digits and then an ASCII letter
  - `[0-9a-zA-Z]*` - zero or more alphanumeric ASCII chars
  - `-` - a `-` char
- `)` - end of the lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

-(?:[a-zA-Z]+\d[a-zA-Z\d]*|\d+[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*)-.*

should also work

just added Capital A-Z

```
import re
test='k8s-configuration-int-mbus_config-int-mbus-deployment-db9c64cd-n4tww_central_6d499584'
print (re.sub(r'(?i)-(?:[a-zA-Z]+\d[a-zA-Z\d]*|\d+[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*)-.*', '', test))
# result 
k8s-configuration-int-mbus_config-int-mbus-deployment
```

basically with sub we are extracting the unmatched part of the string that is suppress the matched values and pick only the unmatched data .

kind of reverse analysis here

Thanks to @anubhava